# How to make an Array Find function recursive

Tags: php, search, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array parsing function that looks for partial word matches in values. How do I make it recursive so it works for multidimensional arrays?

```
function array_find($needle, array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($needle, $value)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Array I need to search through

```
array(
 [0] =>
  array(
   ['text'] =>'some text A'
   ['id'] =>'some int 1'
 )
 [1] =>
  array(
   ['text'] =>'some text B'
   ['id'] =>'some int 2'
 )
 [2] =>
  array(
  ['text'] =>'some text C'
  ['id'] =>'some int 3'
 )
 [3] =>
  array(
  ['text'] =>'some text D'
  ['id'] =>'some int 4'
 ) 
etc..
```

Comment: You could use an implementation of [RecursiveFilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php).

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504685/php-find-parent-key-of-array

Comment: @afuzzyllama, no - I have the key. I need to check if a partial word match exists in any of the values and then get the associative key=>value back. This finds whole value matches and then gives you the parent key, which I don't really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function array_find($needle, array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return $key . '->' . array_find($needle, $value);
        } else if (false !== stripos($needle, $value)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you could modify this function to return an array of keys to the target needle, i give you a breadcrumb like string.

Comment: Good call on identifying the parent array in the output result.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to overload your function with an array test...

```
function array_find($needle, array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            array_find($needle, $value);
        } else {
            if (false !== stripos($needle, $value)) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: sorry had window open so long 65Fbef05 beat me to it with the same solution

Answer (score 0):

These solutions are not really what I'm looking for. It may be the wrong function to begin with so I created another question that expresses the problem in a more generalized way.

[Search for partial value match in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932438/search-for-partial-value-match-in-an-array)