# Where like queries on multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a php array like this:

```
$shop = array( array("name"=>"Tom", "level"=> 1.25 ),
               array("name"=>"Mike","level"=> 0.75 ),
               array("name"=>"John","level"=> 1.15 ) 
             );
```

I want to filter this array similar to filtering a mysql table with where conditions. Supposedly I want every array where level is higher than 1. I could iterate through and check with if statements. Are there any php solutions to this?

Comment: This might Interest you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972025/implementing-mongodb-like-query-expression-object-evaluation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is what you are looking for:

```
$results= array_filter($shop, function($item) { return $item['level'] > 1; });

print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Tom
        [level] => 1.25
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [name] => John
        [level] => 1.15
    )
)
```

Comment: I wanted to up-vote but your current reputation of 666 is far too perfect.