# sift.js(MongoDB inspired array filtering library) PHP port

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb, porting, query-expressions

There's a [`sift.js`](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js) library, which allows you to use ***MongoDB syntax*** to *query* JavaScript arrays.

I've asked for a such PHP class in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972025/implementing-mongodb-like-query-expression-object-evaluation), and got several answers so far with good examples, but they still have some compatibility and performance issues(which I hope will be corrected).

Now I've found that such library already exists in JavaScript, and as it is pretty like PHP.

I wonder - would it be difficult to ***port this library*** to PHP, preserving it's style and look, without using PHP SPL?