# Finding item in a JSON Array using PHP

Tags: php, json

I looked for an good answer but found none.

An API returns JSON like this `[{id:31, name:"blue"},{id:22, name:"green"},..]`

I would like to like to get the name from id `$api->[where id= 2]`

The only way I found was to convert this array to obj and having the id as key. Is there no better PHP way?

Comment: You can loop over the array and look for the item that has ID=2

Comment: Will `id:2` always be the 2nd position? If so you could do `echo $json[1]['name']`

Comment: This might interest you ... [Implementing goMongoDB-like Query expression object evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972025/implementing-gomongodb-like-query-expression-object-evaluation)

Comment: No @Sean i fixed it to be more clear (am I doing the @ sean wrong?)

Comment: Good read @Baba, I'll keep this in mind when I have a bigger project. I think it would be a bit of an overkill :)

Comment: Oh ok ... then array_filter can easily fix what you want ...

Answer (score 4):

Your solution *is* the best way. Something like:

```
$results = json_decode($returned_JSON_string);

foreach($results as $result) {
    if($result->id == 2) {
        // Match!
        break;
    }
}
```

If you don't like the default behavior of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) creating an `object`, you can instruct it to create an `array` like this:

```
 $results = json_decode($returned_JSON_string, true);
```

Comment: Is this okay? ( it works but I had to add 'id' infront of numbers to do so. I'm not that pro in PHP. )

`$Obj = new stdClass();
foreach ($jobs as $item)
{
    $key = 'id'.$item['id'];
    $Obj->$key = $item;
}

print_r($Obj->id12);`

Comment: It would work if you absolutely knew that ID `12` existed, but I'd go with the safer approach and loop through as I suggested. That way, you can just execute whatever you need to do with a particular ID (`2`, in my example, `12` in yours) where I commented `// Match!`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just encode your `json` as associative array

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true); //note true as second parameter because we want as associative array
```

and now you can call it with

```
echo $arr[1]['id'];
```

or loop in the array.

Comment: That only works if the id's are 1,2,3?
I fixed the example to be more clear, the id's are very random it would be wonderful if I can say that id should be the key for the associative array

Answer (score 2):

You could use array_filter:

```
$results = json_decode($returned_JSON_string);
$item = array_filter ($results, function($item) { $item['id'] == 2; });
```

Comment: (This is not a comment on the correctness of dave's answer or the appropriateness of it, it's a fine answer.) I always find these anonymous-function solutions hard to read. array_filter, array_map, array_reduce are all hard to figure out what is happening from a quick read. jterry's (simple) answer is much easier to read. It's probably because I'm not as comfortable with functional programming, but so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for doing it in javascript

```
function myIndexOf(arr, o) {    
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].id == o) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    var data = [{id:1, name:"blue"},{id:2, name:"green"}];

    alert(data[myIndexOf(data,2)].name);
```

PHP version

```
    function myIndexOf($arr, o) {    
            for (var i = 0; i < count(arr); i++) {
                if ($arr[i]['id'] == o) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

$data = json_decode($json_data);
echo $data[myIndexOf($data, 2)]['name']; // will output 'green'
```

Comment: my bad, I overlooked that he wanted the solution in PHP

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb If you'll edit your answer, I can remove the down vote.