# Find a parent key in a multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to find out the correct key that contains the array selected. Right now the code echoes out the next array key of 3 and not 2. This seems very basic. I could fix this by simply subtracting 1, but that seems problematic because the last artist array echoes a position of 0. Can anyone help?
(I need to find this key so I can properly set next and previous values.)

sample_entries.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entries>
    <entry>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <id>koons_jeff</id>
        <firstname>Jeff</firstname>
        <lastname>Koons</lastname>
        <bcountry>US</bcountry>
        <byear>1955</byear>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <rank>2</rank>
        <id>richter_gerhard</id>
        <firstname>Gerhard</firstname>
        <lastname>Richter</lastname>
        <bcountry>DE</bcountry>
        <byear>1932</byear>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <rank>5</rank>
        <id>doig_peter</id>
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
        <lastname>Doig</lastname>
        <bcountry>UK</bcountry>
        <byear>1959</byear>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <rank>7</rank>
        <id>marden_brice</id>
        <firstname>Brice</firstname>
        <lastname>Marden</lastname>
        <bcountry>US</bcountry>
        <byear>1938</byear>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

index.php

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('sample_entries.xml');
$path = $xml->xpath('entry');
//strip simple xml tags.
$array = json_decode( json_encode($path) , 1);
print_r($array);
// cannot change the above XML structure.

echo '<br><br>';


// set page's unique identifier.
$artist = 'doig_peter'; 


foreach($array as $element => $inner_array) { 

    if($artist == $inner_array[id]) {
        $current_artist = $inner_array;
        extract($current_artist);
        echo '<b>Current Artist: </b>'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' - '.$bcountry.'-'.$byear.'<br><br>';
        echo key($array); 
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the current output front the above code. I would like the last number "[3]" to report the correct key that contains the data for the id, which is "[2]":

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [rank] => 1 [id] => koons_jeff [firstname] =>
>   Jeff [lastname] => Koons [bcountry] => US [byear] => 1955 ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [rank] => 2 [id] => richter_gerhard [firstname] => Gerhard
>   [lastname] => Richter [bcountry] => DE [byear] => 1932 ) [2] => Array
>   ( [rank] => 5 [id] => doig_peter [firstname] => Peter [lastname] =>
>   Doig [bcountry] => UK [byear] => 1959 ) [3] => Array ( [rank] => 7
>   [id] => marden_brice [firstname] => Brice [lastname] => Marden
>   [bcountry] => US [byear] => 1938 ) )
>
> Current Artist: Peter Doig - UK-1959
>
> 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Find parent key of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504685/php-find-parent-key-of-array)

Comment: Is it just me or the question seems unclear?... Maybe it could be rephrase or restructure so the question is clearer? Could you add a section with the results?

Comment: Sebastien, I added the results to help explain. Mike, I tried to figure out the code that you linked to but was unsuccessful. I just started teaching myself php about 1 month ago and I am figuring things out day by day, but adapting other code is still a challenge for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo key($array);
```

you want

```
echo $element;
```

since $element is the variable assigned in your foreach loop to hold the current key.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something. I kept on trying to return the element key by stating "echo key($element);" which returned an error. This helps me considerably!