# Collapse multidimensional associative array so node is converted to false if all subnodes are false

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional associative array, where each node can have a variable number of child nodes. Each of the child nodes will end with a boolean node at some point. What I want to do is make it so that if all child nodes end with false, the parent will be changed from an array to the boolean false.

Example input array:

```
[
    [Agronomy] => [
        [blendingAnhydrous] => [
            [blendingSprayOrdersDeliveryTkts] => [
                [add] => true,
                [create] => true,
                [inquire] => true,
                [delete] => true
            ],
            [historyInquiry] => [
                [add] => false,
                [create] => true,
                [inquire] => false,
                [delete] => true
            ],
            [listAnhydrousTicketsToBeBilled] => [
                [add] => false,
                [create] => false,
                [inquire] => false,
                [delete] => false
            ],
        ],
        [main] => [
            [agronomyBlendingAnhydrousEntry]: false,
            [agronomyRecomendationsHistory]: false,
            [agronomyReports]: false,
            [agronomySetup]: false
        ],
    ],
    [Grain] => [
        [main] => [
            [option1] => false,
            [option2] => false,
            [option3] => false,
        ]
    ]
]
```

Desired output array:

```
[
    [Agronomy] => [
        [blendingAnhydrous] => [
            [blendingSprayOrdersDeliveryTkts] => [
                [add] => true,
                [create] => true,
                [inquire] => true,
                [delete] => true
            ],
            [historyInquiry] => [
                [add] => false,
                [create] => true,
                [inquire] => false,
                [delete] => true
            ],
            [listAnhydrousTicketsToBeBilled] => false
        ],
        [main] => false
    ],
    [Grain] => false
]
```

Code I've tried so far:

```
function collapseAuthorities(&$complexArray)
{
    $keepExpanded = false;
    foreach ($complexArray as $node => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->collapseAuthorities($value);
            if (!$keepExpanded) {
                $value = false;
            }
        } elseif ($value === true) {
            $keepExpanded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've gone through lots of SO questions regarding multidimensional arrays, but haven't found anything that quite answers this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively scan the $values:

```
$rewriteArray = array();
foreach($mainParentArray as $key=>$value) {

    $rewriteArray[$key] = decompose($value);

}

function decompose($value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        list($array_as_value, $false_found) = keyScan($value);
        if ($array_as_value) {
            dendriticReconstruct($value);
        } else {
            $return = $false_found ? false : $value;
        }
    } else {
        $return = $value;
    }
    return $return;
}

function keyScan($value) {
    $array_as_value = $false_found = false;
    foreach($value as $k=>$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $array_as_value = true;
            break;
        } else {
            if ($v === false) {
                $false_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return array($array_as_value, $false_found);
}

function dendriticReconstruct($value) {

    //use method found at this post ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504685/php-find-parent-key-of-array

}
```

I can't quite finish it - it is taking me too long. I hope this gets you started in the right direction!

Comment: This is closer, but it collapsed [Agronomy] even though it had a true child node. I got this: `[ [Agronomy] => false, [Grain] => false ]` instead of the desired output above. If any of the children are true, then the array node needs to remain expanded. Only collapse if all children are false.

Comment: Collapsed it to a single false? as in [Agronomy] => false

Comment: It collapsed to `[ [Agronomy] => false, [Grain] => false ]`

Comment: I couldn't finish this because it is taking me too long - I hope my answer helps you to complete your task

Comment: It definitely looks like it's on the right track. Thanks for your time and effort on this.